# How to fetch past deposits in Ripple

Tags: ripple

Currently I have setup ripple mainnet server and provide availability of XRP trading, If any user submits the transaction in his account from the external wallet, How I know which transaction performed? 
Currently, I have used WebSocket socket and subscribe all account to the listener, So when any transaction comes in subscribed account then it will catch the transaction. But the issue is that when my xrp server is down or listeners missed any transaction then how we fetch incoming transaction later.

Answer (score 0):

When you get your next transaction.

You check that account's `PreviousTxnLgrSeq` and see if that matches with the latest tx on your end. You can find that from the [account_info](https://developers.ripple.com/websocket-api-tool.html#account_info) API method.

Or you can query [account_tx](https://developers.ripple.com/websocket-api-tool.html#account_tx) to see if the latest tx you got on your end matches with just previous tx. And if those don't match,... you've got the answer above in the `account_tx` method.

One downside to this practice is that you have to wait until someone deposits again to that particular account.

To avoid such circumstances, you can track every accounts' `latest tx ledger sequence` on your end. So if you've missed some `ledgers` you would know which accounts are lagging behind and check if those accounts have transactions that you've missed using `account_tx` method with the `ledger_index_min` set to the `latest tx ledger sequence` and `ledger_index_max` set to `-1`.
In other words this means `check this account's transactions since i've last checked until the latest ledger`... anyway I hope you get the idea. Godspeed! ;)